# MessageQueue non durable messages

Tags: wcf, message-queue, msmq

With WCF message queueing you can configure the netMsmqBinding for non durable queuing.

But I can't find how to setup the basic MSMQ MessageQueue or Message class for non durable messaging. Not in the properties list nor on web.

Is this possible? How can we do that?

Why I'm asking this in the end is that I want to test if the 4MB maximum message size still counts for non durable messages

Answer (score 1):

To set up a non-durable message queue:

1. Just create a private queue and do not make it transactional.

That's pretty much it.

Comment: So it's impossible to switch to a non durable message when the size is over 4MB?

Comment: If having transactional queues is the only way to send messages >4MB then yes

Answer (score 0):

The 4MB message size is fundamental. You can send a larger message using various processes but it has to be cut into 4MB chunks for delivery and reconstituted at the other end. These messages would be sent within one single transaction to guarantee sequence order and delivery.

[Why is there a 4MB limit on MSMQ messages?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/johnbreakwell/2007/08/22/why-is-there-a-4mb-limit-on-msmq-messages/)